# Difference between WHERE clause and HAVING clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How do understand if I should be using a WHERE clause or a HAVING clause with a GROUP BY clause? I've read that WHERE clause is used when we want to place conditions on individual rows and HAVING clause while placing conditions on multiple rows. But even with this definition, I'm confused when to use which.

I would really like to have a very clear and precise distinction! If any additional information is required, do let me know in the comments.

EDIT: I would also like to ask if it is safe to use the HAVING clause instead of WHERE clause every time I use a GROUP BY clause. This way, I mightn't worry about distinguishing between the two any more.

Comment: Hello, @user196012. Welcome to Database Administrators. Please, add the example so that your question can get a more accurate answer. Remember that your question might clarify doubts from other peers too.

Answer (score 2):

The WHERE clause is used to filter the rows that *go into* the grouping operation.

The HAVING clause is used to filter the rows *coming out* of the grouping operation.

```
select * 
from table1 ; 

+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| A | 1 | 
| B | 1 | 
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 1 | 
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| C | 4 |
+---+---+

select a, b 
from table1 
where b >= 3     -- filter on value of column b 
order by a ; 

+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| B | 3 |
| C | 3 |
| C | 4 |
+---+---+

select a, count( b ) tally     -- count entries ... 
from table1 
where b >= 3 
group by a                     -- ... within each value of a 
order by a ; 

+---+-------+
| a | tally |
+---+-------+
| B |     1 |
| C |     2 |
+---+-------+

select a, count( b ) tally 
from table1 
where b >= 3 
group by a 
having count( b ) >= 2     -- filter on calculated value of count( b ) 
order by a ; 

+---+-------+
| a | tally |
+---+-------+
| C |     2 |
+---+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that a simple concrete example is of benefit here (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e9ca70d040453a0119d69c0cc513f23c)). SQL is all about `SELECT`ing subsets of your data based on various criteria as determined by your particular needs.

I like what @PhilW. [wrote](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/254352/34007) - it's one way of looking at it.

> The `WHERE` clause is used to filter the rows that go into the
>   grouping operation.
>
> The `HAVING` clause is used to filter the rows coming out of the
>   grouping operation.

I prefer to think it's more that `WHERE` is a filter for `SELECT` and `HAVING` is a filter for `GROUP BY`.

Sample table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE car
(
  model VARCHAR (25)  NOT NULL,
  price INTEGER       NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO car VALUES 
('Porsche', 100000), ('Porsche', 150000), ('Opel', 15000), ('Opel', 20000),
('Audi', 50000), ('Audi', 75000);
```

Check (always check!):

```
SELECT * FROM car
ORDER BY price DESC; -- **ALWAYS** have an `ORDER BY` clause in your SQL!
```

Result:

```
model   price
Porsche 150000
Porsche 100000
Audi    75000
Audi    50000
Opel    32000
Opel    20000
Opel    15000
```

All good! So, first we do a simple `SELECT` with a `WHERE`:

```
SELECT * FROM car WHERE price > 30000;
```

Result:

```
model   price
Porsche 150000
Porsche 100000
Audi    75000
Audi    50000
Opel    32000
```

So, we have eliminated the models with a price < 30000 - easy enough!

Then, we get the average price per model.

```
SELECT 
  c.model,      -- try removing both the model and the GROUP BY clause and see what happens!
  AVG(c.price) AS av_price
FROM car c
GROUP BY model  -- try removing just the GROUP BY clause and see what happens!
ORDER BY AVG(price) DESC;
```

`AVG` is an [aggregate function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx) - these functions are very important and well worth studying/mastering!

Result:

```
model   av_price
Porsche 125000.0000
Audi    62500.0000
Opel    22333.3333
```

Which is the average price for every model - no `WHERE` or `GROUP BY`. If you have an aggregate function with another field, you have to have a `GROUP BY`. This is logical - if you want an average by model, you have to group the average with the model!

So, then we run:

```
SELECT 
  c.model, 
  AVG(c.price) AS av_price
FROM car c
WHERE price > 30000
GROUP BY model
ORDER BY av_price DESC;
```

Result:

```
model   av_price
Porsche 125000.0000
Audi    62500.0000
Opel    32000.0000   <<-- not relective of reality!
```

So, we have the average prices of the Porsches, the Audis **and** the Opels where the price of the Opel is > 30000. **BUT**, this is not reflective of the true average of the Opels - we only have the "average" of one model, the most expensive. Our result is flawed!

So, what we have to do is:

```
SELECT 
  c.model, 
  AVG(c.price) AS av_price
FROM car c
GROUP BY model
HAVING AVG(c.price) > 30000  -- NOW the average will be more reflective of reality
ORDER BY AVG(c.price) DESC;
```

Result:

```
model   av_price
Porsche 125000.0000
Audi    62500.0000
```

So, (depending on your requirements), this result is a truer reflection of the average value of the average of the more expensive models.

Now, you might say to yourself, why not put the `AVG(c.price)` in the `WHERE`clause? Try it and see - check the fiddle. I'll admit, this used to puzzle me (and to a certain extent, the theoretical underpinnings still do), but this diagram is helpful.

From [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx),

[image]

You can only filter `GROUP BY`s on aggregates in the `HAVING` clause and, to a certain extent, the `LIMIT` clause (but `LIMIT` would depend on previous knowledge about what numbers of records fit what conditions). An excellent discussion of this area is to be found [here](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/). You can also use the table above (without the `HAVING`) as a table in a sub-select, but, in this case, `HAVING` is far more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

The case when `GROUP BY` clause is present in the query text is explained in https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/254352/150107 and https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/254364/150107 .

But `HAVING` clause may be used in the case when `GROUP BY` clause is **NOT** present in the query text. In this case there is only one difference between `WHERE` and `HAVING` - the conditional expressions in `HAVING` may use/refer to the names/aliases of the fields in the output fieldset. Whereas the attempt to refer to them in `WHERE` will produce "unknown field" error.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to apply condition on a column which are actually in table you should use **WHERE** clause.

When you have applied any calculation or any condition on fetched data from the table and you want to apply condition on that at that time you must have to use **HAVING** if you will use WHERE it won't work.

Don't think too much on this, Just focus on what you want to get from table, you will automatically come to know that where you have to use **WHERE** clause and where **HAVING**

**GROUP BY** will be used when you want to get unique data on specific column from the table.

Comment: You _can_ have expressions in the `WHERE` clause, but they must not reference "aggregate" functions, such as `SUM()`.

Comment: *When you have applied any calculation or any condition on fetched data from the table and you want to apply condition on that at that time you must have to use HAVING if you will use WHERE it won't work.* is explaining the same thing which you explain in above comment might be in simple language as he has mentioned in the question.